# Particle Ring Simulation (Asteroid Belt)

Tags: particles

I have a set of particle simulations attached to rings around a planet. When I run the simulation they circle correctly but they start traveling out and away from the rings.

Is there a way to get the particles to still move and rotate yet stick / adhere to the rings?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use geometry node to do this.

[image: geo node set up]

The two attributes nodes add some randomness to scale and rotation

The rotation of ateroids is animated with the point rotate node (only on X axis for instance).

The point instance node add an instance to all vertex on the circle wich is modified by geometry node

You can add displace modifier before GeoNode modifier in the modifier stack to get more randomness or you can even edit your circle

Comment: wow this is awesome

Answer (score 0):

If you want the asteroids to rotate on themeselves maybe you could create a bunch of asteroids, make them rotate on themselves, put them into a collection, give a *Hair* particle system to a circle, choose *Render As > Collection*, and enable the *Rotation* option, then make the circle rotate on itself.

Comment: Would setting it Hair vs Emitter still allow normal rotation characteristics? or would I have to redo most the values? I will try your suggestions though. I thank you.

Comment: what kind of rotation are you planning to do?

Comment: It's generally a simulation of rings around a planet.. With a bunch of rocks that I created  that the particle system is choosing from. 

They need to rotate around the planet on a whole...  and then move a bit freely so that they look natural and not static.

Comment: yes so it would be interesting to find the best way to instance the rocks and make them rotate on themselves... Maybe instances of collection? It will take the meteorites rotations into accoun